# Assigning a variable by running script from cell in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for data issues, with the code that identified it, and a separate table with the figures for how many rows it affects, what I want to do is use the script (example code) to update the current number of rows (week1)

I have set up a loop so it will pick up the script from that cell and assign is to a variable. To get an output I would ordinarily just exec the variable, but as I want this to update the cell, I'm trying to get it to alter the week1 detail, but get a syntax problem trying to do anything with the exec apart from just exec it

```
declare @srow int, @erow int, @example varchar(max)

set @srow = 1
set @erow = (select max(id) from @log)

while @srow <= @erow
BEGIN

set @example = (select ExampleCode from @DQLog where ID = @srow)

update @log
set Week1 = exec (@example)
where id = @srow

set @srow = @srow + 1

END
```

The @example should be set to the examplecode script, and then the execute gives the result and assigns it to the week1 column, but that's not acceptable in mssql. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use exec to return a value from a select.  One way to do this is to use a temp table to hold the value such as:

```
declare @srow int, @erow int, @example varchar(max)

set @srow = 1
set @erow = (select max(id) from @log)

CREATE TABLE #tmp(ID INT)


while @srow <= @erow
BEGIN

set @example = select ExampleCode from @DQLog where ID = @srow

TRUNCATE TABLE #tmp

INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC @example

update @log
set Week1 = (SELECT TOP 1 ID from #tmp)
where id = @srow

set @srow = @srow + 1

END
```

If you had modified your script in the table to have it return a variable such as:

```
set @example = 'select @ExOut = ExampleCode from @DQLog where ID = ' + CAST(@srow as varchar(5))
```

You could use sp_executeSql to return that value to a variable instead:

```
DECLARE @nOut int
EXEC sp_executesql @example, N'@ExOut int OUTPUT', @ExOut = @nOut OUTPUT
```

Comment: You are close, but as I read on his comments he is getting the code to execute from DQLog, so, his original set @example = (select ExampleCode from ....) was correct

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I will use the original example. Worked a treat

Comment: @Daniel Brughera I edited the text but somehow approved/denied/approved your edits.

Comment: No idea what it means but no problem... PS. you missed the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Having understood your question better. This is the way to execute your code.

```
execute sp_executesql @examplecode;
```

Comment: Yes, examplecode is the code I want to execute, not the result. The examplecode cell contains `select id from datatable where id2 is null` or similar.

Comment: ah sorry, exec assumes you are using a stored procedure, you need to use    execute sp_executesql @example;